# df.loc with NaN is not changing anything

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to change my data frame but nothing is happening?

```py
df.loc[(df['var1'] == np.nan) & (df['var2'] == np.nan) & (df['var3'] >=0), 'var2'] = 0
```

Comment: `df.loc[df[['var1', 'var2']].isna().all(axis=1) & df['var3'].ge(0), 'var2'] = 0`

Comment: Perhaps you're not assigning to `df` (operations return a reference to a dataframe, they don't modify the original unless `inplace=True`)

Comment: inplace is not neccesary @ti7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['var1'] == np.nan` Never been True, Because np.nan not equal to anything not himself ! . you can check np.nan value as `df.var1.isna()` or in single value case `value is np.nan`. if `x` is single value `np.nan`, and you try: `x == np.nan` the result is False, you should do `x is np.nan`.

Solution

```python
df.iloc[(df[['var1', 'var2']].isna().all(1)) & (df.var3 >= 0), 'var2'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to fill nan values with zero and for that, you can use:

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].fillna(0)
```

or

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].replace(np.nan, 0)
```

If this was not what you asked, please comment!!